# Different level TTL driving each other? A problem?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I connected a GPIO of a 3.3V level board ([schematic](https://github.com/openmv/openmv-boards/blob/master/openmv3/openmv3.pdf), pin is 5V tolerant) as output to a 5V Atmega328p ([schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf)) pin configured as INPUT_PULLUP.

I perform a low active control function with that.

The 3.3V device is going into a deep sleep mode from time to time. During this time the 3.3V GPIOs are floating, that's why the input pullups are configured on the Atmega328p.

Is there current flowing between the 5 V input pin and the 3.3 V output pin if the output is high? Does that do any harm to the 3.3V IC as the levels are not equal?

---

Schematics:

OpenMV3 3.3V

[image]

Arduino 5V (Atmega328P)

[image]

Comment: I have to configure the input pin with pullup, because for battery saving reasons the 3.3V IC does to a deep sleep mode from time to time. During deep sleep the pin is floating and triggering unwanted events on input pin side.

Comment: Pins have almost always esd protection diodes. A higher voltage at a pin will flow to the vcc (3.3v) via that diode. When a pin is 5v tolerant, there is an other circuit to avoid a large current. However, when the pin is set as high output, there is probably some kind of fet transistor that connects the output to vcc. A fet transistor can let the current go in the opposite direction without problem, so the current will flow via the pin to the vcc (3.3v). The internal pullup resistor of the atmega328p has a high value, there is probably no problem with that current.

Comment: @user259819, please edit your question to include the information about the deep-sleep requirement. That entirely changes what answers will be useful to you.

Comment: A datasheet for the 3.3-V board would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 5-V device with GPIO configured as "pull-up", you will likely have this pull-up as equivalent to 30 - 70 kΩ resistor.

When you connect this "input with pull-up" to a 3.3V-powered IC, it is very likely that the current from 5-V will flow into the 3.3 V device via protective ESD structures (ESD clamps). Assuming the clamp will take 0.7 V (standard diode), you will have 5V - 3.3V - 0.7V = 1V difference across the pull-up resistor.

[image]

Which doesn't make much of a current, 1/30k = 30 uA maximum. It won't hurt anything, and the 3.3V GPIO likely can withstand much more - that's where "5-V tolerant" comes.

However, the problem usually arises when this 3.3V device gets unpowered (sometimes, for power saving reasons etc.). Then the leakage from the 5-V side pull-up will charge the 3.3V IC power rail to some intermediate level - 1.5- 2V or something, which is very bad for internal POR (Power-On-Reset) circuits, and likely will result in ugly intermittent malfunction of the entire design.

Comment: The 3.3 V device is still connected to GND and 3.3V, its ARM processor is just in a deep sleep mode, where its battery power domain (containing an RTC) is still active.
Both devices share same power source. Does, given those information charging up of 3.3 power rail still happen?

Comment: @user259819 "charging up of 3.3 power rail still happen?" no, the powered 3.3v rail will continue to hold the 3v3 level, and no problem should arise.